# Lots of methods in activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, mvvm, mvp

I seem to have a lot of methods/logic in my MainActivity, I am making a simple application that can play sounds, saves them to the storage, share them or set them as ringtone/notification sound.

After implementing all the required actions my `MainActivity` was full of methods with lots of logic in them and I felt like this should/could be better. I tried moving methods with lots of LoC (around 50) like `setAsRingtone();` to a helper class like `RingtoneHelper` as a static method and call it like `RingtoneManager.setAsRingtone(this, sound);`. I could do this for other methods as well like `saveToStorage();` and `share();`. This would make my Activity a lot more readable but after some searching I found out that using helper classes with mostly static methods are frowned upon.

I could make the methods private and do it like this: `new RingtoneManager(context).setAsRingtone(sound);` but to me this seems like the same thing with more overhead.

How can I keep my Activities clean without too much logic in them? I am aware of patterns like MVP or MVVM but I'd like to know how this can be achieved with the traditional way of designing my application or should I bail out now and start using a pattern like MVP? If yes, what pattern?

I appreciate some input

Comment: You can use helper classes with instance methods if static is your concern, also it is recommended to use some design pattern sooner than later.

Comment: I agree, why not just declare an instance of your object : RingtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(); and then use it in your activity

Comment: @RahulTiwari what pattern would you recommend I take a look that?

Comment: @YvesDelerm it is not that static is my concern, I am just looking for a good way to split my logic from my Activity.

Comment: I don't see any need to split up the `Activity` methods and transform them into some object oriented access unless there's some benefits you could take advantage of, like re-usability or state saving, etc.  Show us more and we can better suggest what you could do if anything

Comment: MVVM is hot right now. You have to evaluate whether it suits your needs. You can learn about view binder library  if you go for MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to stick to a single concept per Class (Single Responsibility). 
The best way it to write a summary statement in plain english describing what the class does - if the statement is too long or contains lots of "and's", then it is doing too much. You want to try and stick to OO concepts, so try to avoid lots of static methods and create classes that have a defined purpose.

You don't always need to adopt a pattern straight away, once you have split up the code, look for duplication and try to eliminate it, this is where a good design pattern can come in.

Comment: For example my ringtone manager has a single responsibility (setting mp3's as ringtone). Does this mean that something like new RingtoneManager(this).setAsRingtone(sound); is the right way?(removing static methods).

Comment: If your application has the ability to change the ringtone in several different areas(Activities for example)- then maybe yes, create some helper class.  But if you're setting the ringtone in one `Activity`, and in a rather simple fashion- why change anything? there would be no purpose in a class to handle it unless you're really trying to make things more readable somehow- but it's likely overkill and flawed since it wouldn't be used in a way where object oriented design excels or where the benefits are realized